# Format input with regex to single character comma single character comma, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Ok, admittedly, my regex skills are fairly wretched (I built this using a regex cheatsheet), and for the most part, this works great, but single characters are bogging me down. If I paste `q w e r t y` into the textbox, I'm expecting to get `q,w,e,r,t,y,` returned, but what it does is return is `q,ue,rt,y`.

```
$("#niftyInput").bind('paste', function(e) {
    var str = this.value.replace(/(\w)[\s,]+(\w?)/g, '$1,$2').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-,]/g, '');
    if (str!=this.value) this.value = str;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/crunchfactory/435dc37o/

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hard to understand the larger context but why not just

```
$("#niftyInput").bind('paste', function(e) {
    var str = this.value.replace(/[\s,]+/g, ',').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-,]/g, '');
    if (str!=this.value) this.value = str;
});
```

or

```
$("#niftyInput").bind('paste', function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[\s,]+/g, ',').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-,]/g, '');
});
```

...but that is not regex related.

Comment: Ok, no one likes a show-off, unless, of course, you not only solve the issue, but optimize the code as well. Well done and thank you very much for helping out! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your regex does:

```
(\w)            [\s,]+                             (\w?)
one character   at least one whitespace or comma   one or zero characters
```

When you have something like `q w e r t y` in your input box, here's how it gets captured:

`'q'` is a word-character and matches `(\w)`, so `'q'` is stored in `$1`
`' '` is a whitespace and matches `[\s,]+`, keep going
`'w'` is a word-character and matches `(\w?)`, so `'w'` is stored in `$2` and the match ends.

That's why `q w e r t y` returns multiple matches in pairs (q,w)(e,r)(t,y), which gets turned into `q,ue,rt,y`.

There are many ways to do what you actually want. Since regex is greedy by default and will match as many characters as possible, you can do this:

`(\w+)[\s,]*`

`(\w+)` Will capture the longest sequence of word characters possible.
`[\s,]*` Will then consider any whitespace and commas after that as part of the "match" but not as part of the `$1` capture.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation - you are 98% ; it makes a lot of sense; my problem is that it makes the textbox very unwieldy now - pasting is ok, typing is nightmarish; do you have any ideas for it? - http://jsfiddle.net/crunchfactory/1yrdupy8/

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm not sure how I'd do it then, honestly. I think I'd remove the last character with `.slice(0, -1)` so you don't put in the extra comma EXCEPT if the key that was pressed was space or comma. The fiddle is dead by the way, not sure what happened.

Or you could just apply it on the "change" event instead of the "keyup", but it would look less fancy.

Answer (score 0):

```
\s+(?=\w)
```

or

```
[\s,]+(?=\w)
```

Try this.Replace by `,`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/77

Comment: That's neat, but it won't capture the values, so it can't be used to replace/limit the values themselves. It might be good enough for the asker's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace spaces with `,` by using:

```
$("#niftyInput").bind('paste', function(e) {
    var str = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, ',').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-,]/g, '');
    if (str!=this.value) this.value = str;
});
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qL2zN5/1)**